# how to automatic trigger the enter button after switching to next input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

hello guys i need to automatic trigger the enter button after the user switch to another html `input type='text'`. i need to do this so that i can validate the form.

here is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="student_lastname" placeholder="Last Name" pattern="[A-Za-z].{1,}" title="Only Letters are accepted and more than 1 letter" required>
```

i need the error `title="Only Letters are accepted and more than 1 letter"` to pop up when the user is finished typing to the box

right now this is what my code looks like

Comment: actually, i havent tried any yet because i dont have idea how to do it. sorry

Comment: For starters you can look up the `blur` function. https://api.jquery.com/blur/. Then you can all the `submit` function of the form when the blur event fired. Something along the lines here: `$('form :input').blur(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onblur` is the perfect solution, and was made specifically for when the user leaves an input field. Just do something like this:

For HTML:

```
<input type="text" onblur="validate()" />
```

And for JS:

```
function validate() {
  // This is how you automatically make them click the Enter button:
  enterButton.click();
}
```

Comment: thanks. how can i select the specific input text using name="" ?

Comment: Use the `HTMLElement#focus()` method: `input.focus();` or `form.inputName.focus();`. Note: if you are doing this on a mouse event, you will likely need to call `e.preventDefault()` on the mouse event handler, as the user-action may override your `focus()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus for more info.

Comment: can i ask how can i chage the patter with this? [A-Za-z]{3}

im getting error sorry

Comment: If you are trying to test for two or more letters like you said in your question,  `/^[A-Za-z]{2,}$/` should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure why `enterButton.click()` doesn't work. Can I see the rest of your code?